# Check if input is emtpy AFTER hitting submit and THEN inserting a value into this field

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I've got an input field and want in case the user doesn't fill the input, that there will be a standard text inserted like "no input" or "this field wasn't filled" as a value of this input.

I have some code that works, but the field is already filled with the standard text instead AFTER the user submitted the form.
So the user already sees the standard text inside of the input field instead of having a chance to fill it himself.

```
var inputStandard = document.getElementById('inputField');

if(inputStandard.value.length == 0)
    inputStandard.value = "this field wasn't filled";
```

Expected is:
-user opens form
-user leave the field empty
-hitting submit
-and THEN the value of the field is changed, not already when the user opens the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate your form with the event `onsubmit`on the form
This function will return `true`if the input ins not empty otherwhise it will display yur message in this input and return `false`

```js
function isValidForm() {

  var inputStandard = document.getElementById("inputField");

  if (inputStandard.value.length == 0) {
    inputStandard.value = "this field wasn't filled";
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return isValidForm()">
  <input type="text" id="inputField" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', check);

function check(e) {
  var inputStandard = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
  if (inputStandard !== "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    //when the form is empty do:
    document.querySelector('.err').innerHTML = "PLEASE FILL THE FORM WITH SOME DATA";
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="inputField">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<p class="err"></p>
```

Comment: Please explain your code - also no need to have the else after a return

Comment: Also the message does not go away after entering data

Comment: you can remove the else statement then make the if statement returns false, what thing you want me to explain to you?

Comment: the message is disappeared after submitting again

Comment: Still there while submitting. You should remove it before testing

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('inputField').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    if(evt.target.value.length == 0){
        evt.target.value = "this field wasn't filled";
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
    }else
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
});
```

Comment: Your solution is nice but this is not the solution he asked for.  the event must be on form submit

Comment: my solution do not allow submit form before complete `inputField`, because `input submit` disabled

Comment: Yes, i see that. But the question is clear `Check if input is emtpy AFTER hitting submit and THEN inserting a value into this field`...  Has i said, your answer is nice but in no way you explain why you use this method instead of one other